# Where can I find/buy Peruvian Parsnip (AKA: Batata Baroa or Arracacha) in the US?

Tags: vegetables, caribbean-cuisine

Not to be confused with the common parsnip that is usually found in regular supermarkets. Either online or in specialty markets that ship via FedEx would be ideal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Peruvian Parsnips seem to be pretty difficult to find, even online. I found this link that has an "Email me when available" option: https://www.greenharvest.com.au/Plants/SummerLeafyGreens.html#PeruvianParsnip

But the website appears to be in Australia and may not ship to the USA, or perhaps if exorbitant shipping costs. I would recommend to also check local health/specialty food stores, they might be able to special-order it through their supply chain.

Another option would be to try and find a substitute that would be "close enough". I don't have suggestions as I have never had Peruvian Parsnips.

---

### Another option: growing them!

I found [this link](http://www.motherearthliving.com/gardening/vegetable-gardening/growing-cooking-root-vegetables-zm0z14sozpit.aspx) which mentioned growing it.

> Root vegetables are easy to grow for gardeners at any level. In most parts of the country, roots you plan to harvest in the fall and winter need to be in the ground by mid- to late-summer. If you live in a warmer climate, you have additional time. Whether you’re going to squeeze in a few roots this year or are already planning next year’s garden, use these tips for root gardening success.

Seems like this tuber mostly grows in more tropical climates, so it may be difficult. I also found [this other article](http://www.realseeds.co.uk/unusualtubers.html) which has information about growing unusual tubers.

If you have questions about that, feel welcome to try our [Gardening Stack Exchange](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) site!

Comment: +1 for growing your own! I'm sure you can get some great advice about that on Gardening.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to find it. Also it has many names depending on the country: Mandioquinha, Batata Salsa, Peruvian carrot, etc... The latin is *Arracacia xanthorrhiza E.N. Bancroft*.

It seems you can find them online at this place in the US (but I have not yet bought them yet).
In general, you will find only frozen. It is impossible to find it fresh in the USA.

http://www.latinfoodsmarket.com/Colombian_Food_Products-Arracacha_Yellow_Cassava_DeliFood.html

Growing them is not an easy option:

1. Seeds are impossible to find since it usually is propagated by tubers, not seeds.
2. Importing tubers requires too much paper work and sanitary inspections.
3. Even in Puerto Rico, where it is suppose to grow, I was not able to find it in the markets.